# WSO2 Identity Server EntitlementService api python example?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm investigating if the WSO2 Identity Server would be a suitable technology to deploy at the company I work at to managed Authorisation control to our applications.

We however write most of our apps in python and so far every example I've found of how to query WSO2is's EntitlementService api seems to be written in java and involve several java libraries that abstract away from the raw data being sent to the server.   So far I've not managed to reverse engineer any of those examples into something that works in python code.

Does anybody have an example of such code written in python?   or even another more minimal approach written in another way/language such as sending the request via curl would be of great help to me in understanding exactly what needs to be sent.

I think I'm having a basic misunderstanding in how the data is supposed to be enscapsulated in the request since every query I've sent so far results in responses like

```
<faultstring>namespace mismatch require http://org.apache.axis2/xsd found urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17</faultstring>
```

Also am I correct in understanding that the current version of WSO2 identity server exposes the EntitlementService api in REST as well as SOAP?   (I've been trying both REST and SOAP formatted requests but I'm not 100% from the documentation I've found if REST is actually valid or not for this api).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no REST interface for XACML in WSO2 IS 5.0.0 but it is planned in a future release not too far from now. Currently there is only a SOAP and a THRIFT inferface.

Try sending a request like this via curl. Note the part between <Request>..</Request> is XACML whereas the rest is WSO2 specific SOAP.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns2:getDecision xmlns="http://dto.entitlement.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://entitlement.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
<ns2:request>
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
<Attribute AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">payroll</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">ssocircle:permissions:paycheck</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request> 
</ns2:getDecision>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks that was quite helpful.